# Compare Date from the database with current date using jpa

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I am using JPA 1 with hibernate as provider. I want to compare date of the entity with current date(regardless of time) and I am saving that field as timestamp(as i need it).
I was getting the correct result when i was using oracle dialect by following code:

```
select t from Task t where to_date(t.createdOn) = to_date(CURRENT_DATE)
```

but when i switch to sql server(2008), it is not working. I need a generic way so that i can make the query database independent.

Answer (score 0):

This is exact analog of your oracle code

```
SELECT * FROM Task t
WHERE CAST(t.createdOn as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

But i recommended use this:

```
SELECT * FROM Task t
WHERE t.createdOn >= cast(getdate() as date)
      AND t.createdOn < DATEADD(d, 1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

**EDIT**

For details how to configure `Hibernate` to work with `SQL SERVER 2008` see [this](http://androidyou.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-test-hibernate-data-access-with.html)

Comment: but it is converting date into datetime datatype and hence comparing full date. We need to compare only date(I tried both and both are comparing full datetime).

Comment: Have you explored `sql server` documentation related to data type `DATE`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx

Comment: I think there is little miss understanding. Hibernate is generating  `datetime`. if I use directly to sql server it is working. So again if you can help please.

Comment: I don't use `Hibernate`, but i assume, that you must configure it to work with `sql server 2008`, because `DATE` is new data type.

Comment: @Hardik Sorry i missed Hibernate with **N** Hibernate.